# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_text_channel'

Tags: python, discord

Всем привет, выдает ошибку, указанную в заголовке. В чем проблема?

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Создает тикет. Если хотите подать жалобу на пользователя используйте /s_report')
async def new(inter, msg):
    if msg is None:
        await inter.send('Вы не указали сообщение для тикета.')
        return
    else:
        guild = bot.get_guild(здесь указываю свой гилд)
        category = disnake.utils.get(inter.guild.categories, name="активные жалобы")
        supportrole = inter.guild.get_role(ид роли)
        authorrole = inter.author
        everyone = inter.guild.get_role(ид роли)
        overwrites_for_ticket = {
            everyone:disnake.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            inter.author:disnake.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
            supportrole:disnake.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
        }
        newticket = await category.create_text_channel(name=f'{inter.author.name} ticket.', overwrites=overwrites_for_ticket)
        await inter.send(f'{inter.author.mention} ваш вопрос был передан модерации. Ожидайте ответа в {newticket}')
        return
```

Comment: а где вы `await category` задали?

Comment: newticket = await category.create_text_channel(name=f'{inter.author.name} ticket.', overwrites=overwrites_for_ticket)

Comment: category = disnake.utils.get(inter.guild.categories, name="активные жалобы")